# If Then Else on 2 separate recordsets

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement, ms-access-2010

I need to test 2 different conditions on 2 separate recordsets. I am not good with VBA, I have a very basic code, I just need help with If Then syntax. Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click()

    '****  add a new record  ****
    Dim db As Database, rs1 As Recordset, rs2 As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("ExpAsset", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("LogTest", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)

'****  Following code is updating the tables in the ExpAsset table with new information     from the form****
If rs1.NoMatch Then
        rs1.AddNew
        rs1("User") = Me!Location
        rs1("Type") = Me!Type
        rs1("Model") = Me!MODEL
        rs1("Asset_ID") = Me!Asset_ID
        rs1("Serial_Number") = Me!Serial
        rs1.Update
Else
        MsgBox "Serial Number: " & Me!Serial & " already exists.", 48, "ERROR!"
        Me!Serial.SetFocus

End If
'****  Following code is creating a log in Logtest table with information provided in the form****
If rs2.NoMatch Then
        rs2.AddNew
        rs2("Asset_Type") = Me!Type
        rs2("Transfer_Type") = "New purchase"
        rs2("Description") = Me!DESCRIPTION
        rs2("DELIVERED_TO") = Me!Location
        rs2("DELIVERED_BY") = Me!DeliveredBy
        rs2("RECEIVED_BY") = Me!Receiver
        rs2("RECEIVED_DATE") = Me!Date
        rs2.Update

        MsgBox "Part information has been updated in the database!"

        'clear the controls to add more customers
        Call ClearControls
Else
        MsgBox "Asset ID: " & Me!Asset_ID & " already exists.", 48, "ERROR!"
        Me!Asset_ID.SetFocus
End If

    rs1.Close
    rs2.Close
    db.Close

End Sub
```

I know The If Then Else syntax is incorrect, I need to check both conditions, serial no. and asset ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right HansUp, my code was silly, I realised later after I had posted that there was no criteria to test against. Following is the right code, I tested it and it works :)

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click()


    '****  add a new record  ****
    Dim db As Database, rs1 As Recordset, rs2 As Recordset, Criteria As String, Criteria2 As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("ExpAsset", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("LogTest", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)

    Criteria = "[serial_number]='" & Me!Serial & "'"
    Criteria2 = "[Asset_ID]='" & Me!Asset_ID & "'"
'****  Following code is updating the tables in the ExpAsset table with new information from the form****
rs1.FindFirst Criteria
If rs1.NoMatch Then
    rs1.FindFirst Criteria2
    If rs1.NoMatch Then
        rs1.AddNew
        rs1("User") = Me!Location
        rs1("Type") = Me!Type
        rs1("Model") = Me!MODEL
        rs1("Asset_ID") = Me!Asset_ID
        rs1("Serial_Number") = Me!Serial
        rs1.Update

'****  Following code is creating a log in Logtest table with information provided in the form****
     rs2.AddNew
        rs2("Asset_Type") = Me!Type
        rs2("Transfer_Type") = "New purchase"
        rs2("Description") = Me!DESCRIPTION
        rs2("DELIVERED_TO") = Me!Location
        rs2("DELIVERED_BY") = Me!DeliveredBy
        rs2("RECEIVED_BY") = Me!Receiver
        rs2("RECEIVED_DATE") = Me!Date
        rs2.Update

        MsgBox "Part information has been updated in the database!"
    'clear the controls to add more customers
        Call ClearControls

    Else
        MsgBox "Asset_ID: " & Me!Asset_ID & " already exists.", 48, "ERROR!"
        Me!Asset_ID.SetFocus
    End If
Else
        MsgBox "Serial Number: " & Me!Serial & " already exists.", 48, "ERROR!"
        Me!Serial.SetFocus

End If

    rs1.Close
    rs2.Close
    db.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please edit my working code, I have next to no knowledge of VBA, all I have here is learning from the internet. Also I am searching for 2 things, Serial_Number and Asset_ID.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Access online help topic for *Recordset.NoMatch Property*:

*Indicates whether a particular record was found by using the **Seek** method or one of the **Find** methods (Microsoft Access workspaces  only).*

However in your code, you're opening a recordset but not using either seek or find.  In that situation, you haven't asked to match anything, so `.NoMatch` will be `False` every time.  The logic is similar to this ...

```vb
If rs1.NoMatch Then
    ' this code will never run
Else
    ' this code runs every time
End If
```

You can use `DCount` to determine whether `ExpAsset` contains a given `Asset_ID` value.

```vb
DCount("*", "ExpAsset", "Asset_ID = " & Me!Asset_ID) ' if Asset_ID is numeric
DCount("*", "ExpAsset", "Asset_ID = '" & Me!Asset_ID & "'") ' if Asset_ID is text
```

Once you have a working `DCount` expression, you can use logic like this ...

```vb
If DCount("*", "ExpAsset", "Asset_ID = " & Me!Asset_ID) = 0 Then
    ' Asset_ID not present in table -> add it
Else
    ' inform user Asset_ID already present in table
End If
```